# Creating Custom ErrorReportValveClass Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Hello guys I don't want the user to see the error page generated by tomcat during exception, I tried to achieve this in two ways,
1. Extend the `ValveBase` class and created my own version of `ErrorReportClass` with the help of [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.java#ErrorReportValve.report%28org.apache.catalina.connector.Request%2Corg.apache.catalina.connector.Response%2Cjava.lang.Throwable%29). Now as per Tomcat documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html) 
I need to give the class name to `errorReportValveClass` attribute of `Host` tag in `sever.xml` which I did, I also converted that class into `.jar` file and along with the other `jars` which are required, placed it in the `lib` folder of `Tomcat` but when I started the server, it says `ErrorReportClass` not found,here is my code
(See the `report()` method which is responsible for printing the error)

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.catalina.Globals;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Constants;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil;
import org.apache.catalina.util.StringManager;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author Kainix
 */
public class ErrorReportValve extends ValveBase {

    public ErrorReportValve() {
        super();
    }
    /**
     * The descriptive information related to this implementation.
     */
    private static final String info
            = "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve/1.0";

    /**
     * The StringManager for this package.
     */
    protected static final StringManager sm = StringManager.getManager(Constants.Package);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------- Properties
    /**
     * Return descriptive information about this Valve implementation.
     */
    @Override
    public String getInfo() {

        return (info);

    }

    /**
     * Invoke the next Valve in the sequence. When the invoke returns, check the response state, and output an error report is necessary.
     *
     * @param request The servlet request to be processed
     * @param response The servlet response to be created
     *
     * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
     * @exception ServletException if a servlet error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Perform the request
        getNext().invoke(request, response);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            return;
        }

//        if (!request.isAsyncStarted()) {
//        } else {
//            return;
//        }

        Throwable throwable
                = (Throwable) request.getAttribute(Globals.EXCEPTION_ATTR);

        if (throwable != null) {

            // The response is an error
            response.setError();

            // Reset the response (if possible)
            try {
                response.reset();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // Ignore
            }

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

        }

        response.setSuspended(false);

        try {
            report(request, response, throwable);
        } catch (Throwable tt) {
            ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(tt);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Prints out an error report.
     *
     * @param request The request being processed
     * @param response The response being generated
     * @param throwable The exception that occurred (which possibly wraps a root cause exception
     */
    protected void report(Request request, Response response,
            Throwable throwable) {

        // Do nothing on non-HTTP responses
        int statusCode = response.getStatus();

        // Do nothing on a 1xx, 2xx and 3xx status
        // Do nothing if anything has been written already
        if ((statusCode < 400) || (response.getContentCount() > 0)) {
            return;
        }

        String message = RequestUtil.filter(response.getMessage());
        if (message == null) {
            message = "";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<html><head><title>");
        sb.append("</head><body>");
        sb.append("This is custom error page..!!");
        sb.append("</body></html>");

        try {
            try {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                if (container.getLogger().isDebugEnabled()) {
                    container.getLogger().debug("status.setContentType", t);
                }
            }
            Writer writer = response.getReporter();
            if (writer != null) {
                // If writer is null, it's an indication that the response has
                // been hard committed already, which should never happen
                writer.write(sb.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            // Ignore
        }

    }

}
```

it also required

- `tomcat-catalina-7.0.47.jar`
- `catalina-6.0.29`

If I use the `catalina.jar` which is provided by the Tomcat it shows error at `Globals.EXCEPTION_ATTR`, anywho this approach isn't working for me since its give me `ClassNotFound` sometimes for my own class and sometimes for classes from the `jar` files, so I tried another method.

2. I downloaded the latest source-code of Tomcat from their site; made changes in`ErrorReportValve.java` file (by modifying the `report()` method just like above). Build the source-code as per the given guidelines and used the newly generated `catalina.jar` file to test whether its giving proper message when an error occurs, but its not.
   So let me know guys where I'm making mistake, I'm well aware of the idea of making an `errorPage` in `jsp` or `html` and configure the global `conf/web.xml` so show those pages when any error occurs, but I don't want to do it that way. Its just too easy hehe..
   Sorry for long question.
   **EDIT**
   When I say its not working, I mean I don't see error page as per the modifications made by me, instead it shows error in its traditional way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second method which I described worked for me, I don't know why it didn't work the first time.
All I did was shared this question with few other friends waited for them to respond (some did) **restarted** the laptop and did ant build once more and it worked.